# Angular-cli from scss to css

Tags: css, angular, sass

Mistakenly I have generated my angular project to scss style but I wanna use css style So there is any way how we can convert scss style to css from Angular-cli ?

Answer (score 3):

you can change angular.json file manually:

```
    "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "css"
    }
 ...
}
```

or if you just created it, simply delete it and generate a new one with css.

Comment: Are you sure It is going to work because still style file name ( style.scss ) will remain same?

Comment: you can rename de file to styles.css, try with that. Another thing to say is that scss recognize all css, so you can write normal css in the scss file and is going to work